# Share state between actix-web server and async closure

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, dereference, rust-tokio, actix-web

I want to periodically fetch data (using asynchronous `reqwest`), which is then served at an http endpoint using `actix-web` as a server.
(I have a data source that has a fixed format, that I want to have read by a service that require a different format, so I need to transform the data.)
I've tried to combine actix concepts with the thread sharing state example from the Rust book, but I don't understand the error or how to solve it.
This is the code minified as much as I was able:

```
use actix_web::{get, http, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

struct AppState {
    status: String,
}

#[get("/")]
async fn index(data: web::Data<Mutex<AppState>>) -> impl Responder {
    let state = data.lock().unwrap();
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .insert_header(http::header::ContentType::plaintext())
        .body(state.status.to_owned())
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let status_string = get_state().await.unwrap();
    let app_data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(web::Data::new(AppState {
        status: status_string,
    })));

    let app_data1 = Arc::clone(&app_data);
    actix_web::rt::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            println!("I get executed every 2-ish seconds!");
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(2000)).await;

            let res = get_state().await;
            let mut app_data = app_data1.lock().unwrap();
            // Edit 2: this line is not accepted by the compiler
            // Edit 2: *app_data.status = res.unwrap();
            // Edit 2: but this line is accepted
            *app_data = web::Data::new(AppState { status: res });
        }
    });

    let app_data2 = Arc::clone(&app_data);
    // Edit 2: but I get an error here now
    HttpServer::new(move || App::new().app_data(app_data2).service(index))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 9090))?
        .run()
        .await
}

async fn get_state() -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new().get("http://ipecho.net/plain".to_string());
    let status = client.send().await?.text().await?;
    println!("got status: {status}");

    Ok(status)
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:33:32
   |
33 |             *app_data.status = res.unwrap();
   |             ----------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `str`, found struct `String`
   |             |
   |             expected due to the type of this binding

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:33:13
   |
33 |             *app_data.status = res.unwrap();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str`
   = note: the left-hand-side of an assignment must have a statically known size

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0308.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Why do I suddenly get a `str`? Is there an easy fix or is my approach to solving this wrong?
`Edit:` Maybe removing the `*` is the right way to go, as *Peter Hall* suggests, but that gives me the following error instead:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to data in an `Arc`
  --> src/main.rs:33:13
   |
33 |             app_data.status = res.unwrap();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Arc<AppState>`

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `app_data2`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:38:49
   |
37 |     let app_data2 = Arc::clone(&app_data);
   |         --------- captured outer variable
38 |     HttpServer::new(move || App::new().app_data(app_data2).service(index))
   |                     -------                     ^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `app_data2` has type `Arc<std::sync::Mutex<Data<AppState>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                     |
   |                     captured by this `Fn` closure

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0507, E0594.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

`Edit 2:` I now get the following error (code changes commented with  'Edit 2' above):

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `app_data2`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:46:49
   |
45 |     let app_data2 = app_data.clone();
   |         --------- captured outer variable
46 |     HttpServer::new(move || App::new().app_data(app_data2).service(index))
   |                     -------                     ^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `app_data2` has type `Arc<Mutex<Data<AppState>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                     |
   |                     captured by this `Fn` closure

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

My `Cargo.toml` dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "4.2.1"
reqwest = "0.11.12"
tokio = "1.21.2"
```

Comment: I think you just need to lose the `*`: `app_data.status = res.unwrap();`

Comment: I have looked at how it was done here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html I think we both missed that `app_data` has type `web::Data`, and I updated the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### async solution

I had my types mixed up a bit, having the app state as `Arc<Mutex<T>>` seemed to be the way to go, maybe it would be better with `Arc<RwLock<T>>`.

```
use actix_web::{get, http, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

struct AppState {
    status: String,
}

#[get("/")]
async fn index(data: web::Data<Arc<Mutex<AppState>>>) -> impl Responder {
    let state = data.lock().unwrap();
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .insert_header(http::header::ContentType::plaintext())
        .body(state.status.to_owned())
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let status_string = get_state().await.unwrap();
    let app_data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(AppState {
        status: status_string,
    }));

    let app_data1 = app_data.clone();
    actix_web::rt::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            println!("I get executed every 2-ish seconds!");
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(2000)).await;

            let res = get_state().await.unwrap();
            let mut app_data = app_data1.lock().unwrap();
            *app_data = AppState { status: res };
        }
    });

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(app_data.clone()))
            .service(index)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 9090))?
    .run()
    .await
}

async fn get_state() -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new().get("http://ipecho.net/plain".to_string());
    let status = client.send().await?.text().await?;
    println!("got status: {status}");

    Ok(status)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### async/sync solution

Instead of doing the async get with reqwest I have a solution with the synchronous crate `minreq` (that I found after a lot of searching). I also chose to not use the `#[actix_web::main]` macro, and instead start the runtime explicitly at the end of my main function.

```
use actix_web::{get, http, rt, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

struct AppState {
    status: String,
}

#[get("/")]
async fn index(data: web::Data<Arc<Mutex<AppState>>>) -> impl Responder {
    let state = &data.lock().unwrap();
    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .insert_header(http::header::ContentType::plaintext())
        .body(state.status.clone())
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let status_string = get_state().unwrap();
    let app_data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(AppState {
        status: status_string,
    }));

    let app_data1 = Arc::clone(&app_data);
    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2000));
        let res = get_state().unwrap();
        let mut app_data = app_data1.lock().unwrap();
        *app_data = AppState { status: res };
    });

    rt::System::new().block_on(
        HttpServer::new(move || {
            App::new()
                .app_data(web::Data::new(app_data.clone()))
                .service(index)
        })
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 9090))?
        .run(),
    )
}

fn get_state() -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let resp = minreq::get("http://ipecho.net/plain").send().unwrap();
    let state = resp.as_str().unwrap();
    Ok(state.to_string())
}
```